# 419 Page Expired, laravel JS

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel-7

espero estén teniendo un buen día.

Deseo ingresar datos a mi base de datos, sin necesidad de recargar página. He visto varios vídeos, y leído varios foros, sin embargo tengo un problema.

Al usar el @section() me lanza error 419 Page Expired, a pesar de que paso el token en el form del html, y también paso el token vía metadato.

Este es el codigo completo:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')


<button id="button">GET NAME</button>
<hr>
<h1>GET FORM</h1>
<form method="GET" action="/prueba">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<h1>AJAX GET FORM</h1>
<form id="getForm">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name1">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<h1>AJAX POST FORM</h1>
<form id="postForm" method="POST">
    @csrf
    <input type="text" name="name2" id="name2">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btnenviar">Probar</button>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".btnenviar").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('probando');
})
</script>
```

Al dar click en el botón Probar, me dirige al error 419 sin antes mostrar la alerta.

@endsection

Comment: Posiblemente esa etiqueta `<script>` esté quedando antes de la que carga jquery. Para poner scripts en vistas que extienden de otra, se recomienda usar [stacks](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#stacks).

Comment: Hola, @BetaM, logré solucionar. Muchas gracias, ahora tengo error, pero creo que lo formularé en otra pregunta.
Básicamente el error era porque en otro post de stackoverflow leí que debía agregar en .env SERVER-DOMAIN=www.midireccion.com, pero eso generaba que no funcionara ningún token.

Comment: Considera publicar tu solución y luego marcarla como aceptada si resolvió el problema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

en este caso en específico, lo que me sucedió fue que en otro post leí que debía añadir en mi archivo .env lo siguiente:

```
SERVER_DOMAIN = tudominio.com
```

Y luego de eso, añadí al formulario el token

```
@csrf
```

La solución fue eliminar el

```
SERVER_DOMAIN = tudominio.com
```

de mi archivo .env, es decir, el problema lo causé yo mismo al añadir eso en mi .env, seguiré investigando más sobre ese statement de laravel.

Gracias por la ayuda.